# Plot subplot axes in separate figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have the following code (modified version of [matplotlib gridspec tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_ticklabels_invisible(fig):
    for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax%d" % (i+1), va="center", ha="center")
        for tl in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
            tl.set_visible(False)


plt.figure(0)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=3)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,0), colspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1, 2), rowspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2, 0))
plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2, 1))  # OOPS! Forgot to store axes object

plt.suptitle("subplot2grid")
make_ticklabels_invisible(plt.gcf())
plt.show()
```

which results in

[image]

How can I 'extract' `ax5` and plot it 'full screen' in a separate figure **without** having to recreate the plot?

Comment: Please post your code that you are using to generate the plot you see above. Always post your code, it makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have reformulated the question. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find anything in official documentation to back up what I'm saying, but my understanding is that it is impossible to "clone" an existing axes onto a new figure.  In fact, no artist (line, text, legend) defined in one axes may be added to another axes.  [This discussion on Github may explain it to some degree](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3835/files).

For example, attempting to add a line from an axes defined on `fig1` to an axes on a different figure `fig2` raises an error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax1.plot([0,1])
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.add_line(line)
>>>RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure`
```

And attempting to add a line that was drawn in `ax1` to a second axes `ax2` on the *same* figure raises an error:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(121)
line, = ax1.plot([0,1])
ax12 = fig1.add_subplot(122)
ax12.add_line(line)
>>>ValueError: Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported
```

The best recommendation I can make is extract the data from the axes you want to copy, and manually plot that into a new axes object that is sized to your liking.  Something like below demonstrates this.  Note that this works for `Line2D` objects plotted via `ax.plot`.  If the data was plotted using `ax.scatter`, then you need to change things just a little bit and I [refer you here for instructions on how to extract data from a scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27852570/5195706).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def rd(n=5):
    # Make random data
    return np.sort(np.random.rand(n))

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
# Plot three lines on one axes
ax1.plot(rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd())

xdata = []
ydata = []
# Iterate thru lines and extract x and y data
for line in ax1.get_lines():
    xdata.append( line.get_xdata() )
    ydata.append( line.get_ydata() )

# New figure and plot the extracted data
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
for X,Y in zip(xdata,ydata):
    ax2.plot(X,Y)
```

Hope it helps.